# Jinja dynamically nested variables

Tags: dynamic, jinja2

So i am trying to nest 2 variables in a `url_for` to pull a specific persons photo.
This is my code

```js
<img
  class="imgContainer"
  src="{{ url_for('static', filename='players/_{{player.username}}_.png') }}"
  />
```

My images are of the form '*username*.png' so thats why I put the '_' at the beginning and end.

This is the Python part of it:

```
@app.route("/<username>")
def player(username):
    player = Player.query.filter_by(username=username).first()    
    return render_template("player.html",player=player)
```

What I tried:

- `{{ url_for('static', filename='players/_[player][username]_.png') }}`
- `{{ url_for('static', filename='players/_player[username]_.png') }}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When setting up your `url_for`, it's already contained in the `{{ }}`. So, you can break up your string + variables like this:

```
<img class="imgContainer"
    src="{{ url_for('static', filename='players/_' ~ player.username ~ '_.png') }}" />
```

Note the use of `~` to concatenate your variable and string within the `{{ }}` syntax. Using the `~` will convert your values to string first. If you know your variable types you can use `+`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just concatenate the string using `+` as you would in Python.

Before:

```
src="{{ url_for('static', filename='players/_{{player.username}}_.png') }}"
```

After:

```
src="{{ url_for('static', filename='players/' + player.username + '.png') }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for replaying